# jinja flask and loop properties

Tags: python, html, templates, flask, jinja2

hello i have the code below on my template but can't get the loop.counter property is there anything wrong on the code?

```
{% for res in res_list %}
 79             <div  id="tr_{{ res.id }}">
 80                         <li><span data-acttion='rename' class="resname edit" id="zaab{{ loop.counter }}">{{ res.id }}</span>
 81 
 82                         <span class="edit resexpr" data-id="{{ res.id }}">{{ res.expr_highlight|safe }}</span></dd>&nbsp;&nbsp;
 83                         <input type="button" id="pickMeUp" value="pickMeUp">
 84                 </div>
 85                 </li>
 86                 {% endfor %}
```

and the problem i have is on line 80 where i have that:

```
id="zaab{{ loop.counter }}"
```

the output on the browser is just zaab

if i change it to loop.first

the output is zaabTrue on first look so there is something with count i think!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok solved i was looking jinja 1 commands in jinja 2.0 that command doesn't even exist so you can use loop.index instead!